# How to test the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}\tan\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to test the convergence of$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}\tan\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)?$$ I'm clueless.

Comment: Does this have a closed form?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says its about 3.2157370938524741. Did you want something else?

Comment: For convergence, we can use $\tan x \to x $ as $x \to 0$

Answer (score 3):

For convergence, $\tan{(1/n)} \sim 1/n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Therefore, the sum converges by the comparison test with

$$\sum_{n-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Hopefully there is still the picture so we can recognize you, +1.

Comment: @julien: Hah!  I decided to change to my actual name based on some advice I stumbled upon in reading the FAQ at Math Overflow.  I will keep the avatar unless I find something more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\sum _ {n \ =1}^{\infty}a_n$$
where $a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \tan {\frac{1}{n}}$
pick a $n_0$ such that $$ \cos (\frac{1}{n})> \frac{1}{2}\, \mathrm{for\,\,}n \geq n_0$$
also note from $ \sin x \leq x \mathrm{for \, \,} x>0$ we get
$$\sin \frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{n}$$
therefore for $n>n_0$ we have $a_n \leq 2 \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ 
and since $\sum \frac{2}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ converges and since $a_n \geq 0$
we conclude that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$converges.